# Error when I click in a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the follow `aspx` page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentConteudo" runat="server">        
    <table border="0" width="680" style="background-color:#f0f0f0" id="tabelaPrincipal" runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 180px !important;">            
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbBuscas" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Novo Curso</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Buscar Lista de Presença</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>           
            </td>
            <td>
                Data: <br />
                <input id="DtBusca" type="text" />                
                <asp:Button id="btnSelecionarData" runat="server" Text="Buscar" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <br /><br />
    <div id="infoGrid" runat="server">
        <cc1:GridView ID="grdImoveis" CssClass="StyleGrid" Width="100%" runat="server" ShowHeader="false"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="dsGrid" BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="None"
            AllowPaging="True" EnableModelValidation="True">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" CssClass="EstiloDalinhaAlternativaGrid" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle CssClass="EstiloDalinhaGrid" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nome">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="<%# Eval("Usuario_Id").ToString() %>">
                           <%# Eval("NomeCompleto").ToString() %>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cargo" DataField="DescricaoCargo1" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Data Cadastro" DataField="DataHora" />
                <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-CssClass="acoes_lista_imovel" HeaderText="Curso">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="acoes_lista_imovel">
                            <%# montaIcones(Eval("Usuario_Id").ToString())%>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div>
                            <%# montaIconesDocumentacao(Eval("Usuario_Id").ToString())%>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </cc1:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsGrid" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <span id="printContrato" class="diasRelatorio btStep ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all"></span>


</asp:Content>
```

The problem occurs when I click in my `<asp:Button>`, I tryied to put the `OnClick` event, but still happens the error.

`<asp:Button id="btnSelecionarData" runat="server" Text="Buscar" />`

**ERROR**

`Failed to load viewstate. The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request. For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.`

**CODE BEHIND**

```
    public partial class ListaUsuarioProvisorio : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        neticonn.Conexao c = new neticonn.Conexao();
        Utilidade.QuebraToken tk = new Utilidade.QuebraToken();
        public string icones = string.Empty;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                this.CarregaLista();
            }
        }

        protected void CarregaLista()
        {
            string select = string.Empty;
            select += "SELECT San_Credenciada.Apelido, San_Usuario.NomeCompleto, San_Usuario.Usuario_Id, San_Usuario.DescricaoCargo1, "
                + "CONVERT(varchar, San_Usuario.DataHora, 103) AS DataHora "
                + "FROM San_Usuario "
                + "JOIN San_Credenciada "
                + "ON San_Usuario.Credenciada_Id = San_Credenciada.Credenciada_Id "
                + "WHERE San_Usuario.Provisorio = 1 "
                + "AND San_Usuario.Excluido = 0 "
                + "GROUP BY San_Credenciada.Apelido, San_Usuario.NomeCompleto, San_Usuario.Usuario_Id, " 
                + "San_Usuario.DescricaoCargo1, San_Usuario.DataHora "
                + "ORDER BY San_Usuario.DataHora ASC ";

            dsGrid.ConnectionString = c.Con;
            dsGrid.SelectCommand = select;
            dsGrid.Dispose();

            GridViewHelper helper = new GridViewHelper(this.grdImoveis);
            helper.RegisterGroup("Apelido", true, true);            
            helper.GroupHeader += new GroupEvent(helper_GroupHeader);
            helper.ApplyGroupSort();
        }

        protected void CarregaLista(string data)
        {
            string select = string.Empty;
            select += "SELECT San_Credenciada.Apelido, San_Usuario.NomeCompleto, San_Usuario.Usuario_Id, San_Usuario.DescricaoCargo1, "
                + "CONVERT(varchar, San_Usuario.DataHora, 103) AS DataHora "
                + "FROM San_Usuario "
                + "JOIN San_Credenciada "
                + "ON San_Usuario.Credenciada_Id = San_Credenciada.Credenciada_Id "
                + "JOIN San_UsuarioCurso "
                + "ON San_Usuario.Usuario_Id = San_UsuarioCurso.Usuario_Id "
                + "WHERE San_Usuario.Provisorio = 1 "
                + "AND San_Usuario.Excluido = 0 "
                + "AND San_UsuarioCurso = " + data + " "
                + "GROUP BY San_Credenciada.Apelido, San_Usuario.NomeCompleto, San_Usuario.Usuario_Id, "
                + "San_Usuario.DescricaoCargo1, San_Usuario.DataHora "
                + "ORDER BY San_Usuario.DataHora ASC ";

            dsGrid.ConnectionString = c.Con;
            dsGrid.SelectCommand = select;
            dsGrid.Dispose();

            GridViewHelper helper = new GridViewHelper(this.grdImoveis);
            helper.RegisterGroup("Apelido", true, true);
            helper.GroupHeader += new GroupEvent(helper_GroupHeader);
            helper.ApplyGroupSort();
        }

        private void helper_GroupHeader(string groupName, object[] values, GridViewRow row)
        {
            string xCol = "#f56d01";
            string yCol = "#cbcbcb";
            Color c = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(xCol);
            Color c2 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(yCol);

            if (groupName == "Apelido")
            {
                row.BackColor = c;
                row.Cells[0].Text = "<div class='AgrupamentoPrincipal'>&nbsp;&nbsp;" + Maiscula(row.Cells[0].Text) + "</div>";
                row.Cells[0].Text += "</div><tr bgcolor=#e2dcd2 class=thGrid><th scope=col height='27'>&nbsp;Nome</th><th scope=col>Cargo</th><th>Data Cadastro</th><th scope=col>Curso Básico</th><th>Documentação Imobiliária</th></tr>";             
            }
        }

        protected string Maiscula(string texto)
        {
            texto = texto.ToUpper();
            return texto;
        }

        protected string montaIcones(string id)
        {
            icones = string.Empty;            
            int Credenciada = Convert.ToInt32(tk.CarregaToken(1, Request.Cookies["token"].Value));
            icones = "<img src='../tema/default/icon/icon-cinza/check.png' onclick=\"Visibilidade('" + id + "', '" + id + "', '" + Credenciada + "')\" style='cursor:pointer;margin: 4px;text-align:center;' ID='" + id + "' />";
            return icones;
        }

        protected string montaIconesDocumentacao(string id)
        {
            icones = string.Empty;
            int Credenciada = Convert.ToInt32(tk.CarregaToken(1, Request.Cookies["token"].Value));
            icones = "<img src='../tema/default/icon/icon-cinza/documents.png' onclick=\"VisibilidadeDocumentacao('" + id + "', 'documentacao_" + id + "', '" + Credenciada + "')\" style='cursor:pointer;margin: 4px;text-align:center;' ID='documentacao_" + id + "' />";
            return icones;
        }

        public void btnSelecionarData_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.rbBuscas.SelectedIndex == 1 && !this.DtBusca.Value.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                this.CarregaLista(this.DtBusca.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Somebody can help me ?

Comment: Please show `btnSelecionarData` button's handler

Comment: When I try to put a `OnClick` the error still happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem typically occurs when you are creating custom controls in your code behind. I would take a look at this article, which goes into depth about the origin of the problem and how you can spot check your code for such issues:

http://blog.typps.com/2008/01/failed-to-load-viewstate-typical.html

Comment: My aspx page, inherit from my master page, so the problem can be in my master page ?

Comment: Yes, it could be in any code behind that's running on your page including master pages, pages, and user controls. According to the article, you should look for dynamic control changes inside of conditionals, especially differences between handling initial page load versus a postback. I will add that this is one of the more frustrating errors in ASP .net, because sometimes it can appear without warning because it involves conditionals, so sometimes it doesn't happen ALL the time.

Comment: This was a good tip, thanks. Just a little observation, I tryied right now to put a `IsPostBack` in my page load. Result: When my page is loaded, my `GridView` is not filled, but if I click in my button, the `GridView` is filled. What I need is, when the page is loaded, my `GridView` has to be filled, and when I click in my button, I need to fill my `GridView` again but with some differents parameter that I pass, but in this wy, occurs the `viewstate` problem.

Comment: That could be where the problem is; are you creating dynamic controls there?

Comment: No, all my components are in my `aspx` page.

Comment: I have another thought, maybe you need to update your gridview in the onPreRender event instead of onLoad... not sure if that will help but sometimes putting your code in a different phase of the ASP .net request lifecycle can help.

Comment: I discover something interesting. If in my `GridView` I comment my first `<asp:TemplateField>` the error with `viewstate` don't appears, and everything runs rightly.

Comment: To be more specific, If I comment the `<%# Eval("NomeCompleto").ToString() %>` in my first `<asp:TemplateField>` the problem don't appears. Strange.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16645/discussion-between-steven-hunt-and-lucas-santos)